# Can't add Canadian Multilingual keyboard layout in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I go to ibus preferences in Lubuntu and can add French (Canada), but it's not the Canadian Multilingual layout. I tried installing m17 ibus packages and it adds a bunch of languages but not more French options (other than the French azerty m17 option). I didn't have this problem in ubuntu, just Lubuntu. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change keyboard layout in Lubuntu 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788244/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-lubuntu-15-10)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setxkbmap` to change your keyboard layout settings. Just open a terminal window and type:

```
setxkbmap ca multix
```

This will get you a Canadian Multilingual Standard keyboard layout. You can also create a desktop launcher with your keyboard layouts. Create a file named `multix.desktop` in `$HOME\Desktop` and open it with a text editor. Add the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/setxkbmap ca multix
Name=Keyboard Layout
StartupNotify=false
Name[fr_CA]=multix
```

If you prefer to use the old Canadian French keyboard layout you can use `setxkbmap ca` and to get back to the US layout use `setxkbmap us`.

Answer (score 0):

For what is it worth in 2022, I just struggled with this.

The name in the Ubuntu 22.04 Input Dialog selection list is
**Canadian Intl**.

You need to go under: Settings> Keyboards> Inputs Sources > Add New

Double click on the Canada French (it is a group and will expand it)
And select **Canadian Intl**.

Answer (score 0):

Now in Ubuntu 23.04, it's named `Canadian (CSA)` instead of `Canadian Multilingual keyboard`.

I was looking for that for a long time >.<

Answer (score -1):

Install package `ibus-xkbd` and in your normal keyboard setup (not `ibus`) choose canadian multilingual, then in choose `xkbd` as a ibus input method and it will be canadian multilingual.