# Key combination to switch language in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, language-support

Can anybody inform me how to switch language in Lubuntu? I went to "Keyboard and Mouse Settings" as well as "Language Support" but couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: Use Super+space like other distros

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/788319).

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha super+space not working!

Comment: Thank you so much @GunnarHjalmarsson! You care about writing an answer so I can confirm it?

Comment: Good to hear that it helped, but if that answered your question, your question is a duplicate, so I mark it as such instead.

Comment: Although the answer from the other question goes a long way towards answering this question, the questions appear distinct and different to me. Also, the answer doesn't give a good way to activate a key combination to switch languages.  Although there is a selection for this in "Keyboard and Mouse Settings," I cannot yet get any key combination work in Lubuntu 18.10 nor 19.04 even after uninstalling iBus and Fcitx. If we unmark this as duplicate might we get some more responses?