# On lubuntu-desktop session there is no language selector

Tags: 16.04

On Ubuntu 16.04.3 i installed the `lubuntu-desktop` via:

```bash
apt-get install lubuntu-session
```

But when I login into `lubuntu-desktop` session I cannot find a way to install the icon/indicator that allows me to switch the language from English into Greek. All the research I did are saying to use `xkbmap` but on "normal" lubuntu disto there is an option to select the language.

The problem is that there is no indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is given in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/788319/540746) but my system settings were in Greek, so for those stuck on this, the Greek equivalent is:

Προσθήκη/Αφαίρεση Αντικειμένων Πλαισίου -> Προσθήκη -> Χειρηστής Διάταξης Πληκτρολογίου