# Keyboard layout change bug (Lubuntu)

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I run Lubuntu 18.04 and I have a problem with the keyboard layout changes. Until recently I used the Greek and the American layout. I now need to write in French for a project so I removed the standard US keyboard layout and I added US, alt.intl. After I did that, each time I try to open a window the default layout (as seen in the panel) become NONE, which I think is the standard US layout. When I switch between my added layout (which should be 2, Greek and US international) they are 3: GR, US and NONE. I tried changing to different international layouts and it does the same. Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

My keyboard doesn't change back to us instead of us intl. It just adds a third layout which is called NONE. I can still switch back to whichever keyboard I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change keyboard layout in Lubuntu 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788244/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-lubuntu-15-10)

Comment: You are right. I solved the problem by typing `localectl set-keymap us` who's value was n/a. Thank you and I'm sorry I didn't noticed it before.

Comment: No, that didn't fix it after all. Only for a moment. It should have been accidental. It happened before and some minutes later it switch again to None. Sorry...

Comment: Try the first answer to the duplicate question. Command line ways may be (and probably are) overridden by desktop facilities for the purpose.

Comment: It is not a duplicate question, I'm sorry. The first answer suggests to add a keyboard handler icon to your panel. I have a keyboard handler to my panel from the day I installed Lubuntu. I tried the other suggestions, nothing works.

Comment: Ok, I just retracted my close vote. I don't have access to Lubuntu right now; hopefully someone who has can help.