# Lubuntu - changing input, adding shortcuts to quicklaunch

Tags: lubuntu, input-method

So after a few years with GNOME, I decided to move to LXDE, and installed Lubuntu on my Laptop.

I'm using two languages on my keyboard. How do I change the keyboard to toggle between them? I've tried to change it in the setting, and it didn't seem to change anything.   How can I configure <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> to change input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change keyboard layout in Lubuntu 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788244/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-lubuntu-15-10)

Comment: One question only at this site. Please edit your question so only one remains, and ask your second question as another question

Comment: @user635034 House rules call for us to limit the scope of a question to one issue at a time. Would you please click [edit], remove the LXDE quicklaunch shortcut issue from this question, and create a new question with it?  Also, please note that, beginning with Lubuntu 18.10, LXDE has been replaced with LXQt; if you installed Lubuntu 18.04, you have LXDE, but if you installed 19.04, you have LXQt. See http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/12/lubuntu-1804-and-1810-between-lxde-and-lxqt.html

Comment: Sorry for that. I've  edited the post.                                                   I'm using 19.04. I'll  try lxkeymap.